# Dynamically supply link to chainlink upkeeper

Tags: solidity, chainlink, polygon, scheduling

I've created a simple chainlink upkeep task on polygon:

```
import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.7/KeeperCompatible.sol";

contract Counter is KeeperCompatibleInterface {
    /**
    * Public counter variable
    */
    uint public counter;

    /**
    * Use an interval in seconds and a timestamp to slow execution of Upkeep
    */
    uint public immutable interval;
    uint public lastTimeStamp;

    constructor(uint updateInterval) {
    interval = updateInterval;
    lastTimeStamp = block.timestamp;

    counter = 0;
    }

    function checkUpkeep(bytes calldata /* checkData */) external override returns (bool upkeepNeeded, bytes memory /* performData */) {
        upkeepNeeded = (block.timestamp - lastTimeStamp) > interval;
        // We don't use the checkData in this example. The checkData is defined when the Upkeep was registered.
    }

    function performUpkeep(bytes calldata /* performData */) external override {
        lastTimeStamp = block.timestamp;
        counter = counter + 1;
        // We don't use the performData in this example. The performData is generated by the Keeper's call to your checkUpkeep function
    }
}
```

I've supplied it initially with 5 link,  I would like my application to be completely decentralized,  How can I dynamically supply the keeper with more link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done using the keeper registry base interface.  This was a proof of concept and once I got it working I stopped optimizing it.

```
interface IERC20 {

function totalSupply() external view returns (uint256);
function balanceOf(address account) external view returns (uint256);
function transfer(address recipient, uint256 amount) external returns (bool);
function allowance(address owner, address spender) external view returns (uint256);
function approve(address spender, uint256 amount) external returns (bool);

function transferFrom(
    address sender,
    address recipient,
    uint256 amount
) external returns (bool);

event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint256 value);
event Approval(address indexed owner, address indexed spender, uint256 value);
}

interface IKeeperRegistry {
function registerUpkeep(
    address target,
    uint32 gasLimit,
    address admin,
    bytes calldata checkData
) external returns (uint256 id);

function performUpkeep(uint256 id, bytes calldata performData) external returns (bool success);

function cancelUpkeep(uint256 id) external;

function addFunds(uint256 id, uint96 amount) external;
}

contract KeeperManager {

    //Default is Mumbai TestNet 0x6179B349067af80D0c171f43E6d767E4A00775Cd
    address public KeeperRegistry;
    address public Target;
    address public chainlinkToken;
    address owner;
    uint256 public upkeepId;
    IKeeperRegistry _keeperRegistry;

    // chain link token address 0x326c977e6efc84e512bb9c30f76e30c160ed06fb
    constructor(address keeperRegistry, address target, address chainlink) {
        KeeperRegistry = keeperRegistry;
        Target = target;
        owner = msg.sender;
        chainlinkToken = chainlink;
        _keeperRegistry = IKeeperRegistry(keeperRegistry);

    }

    function supply(uint256 upkeepId, uint96 amount) external {
        IERC20(chainlinkToken).approve(KeeperRegistry, amount);
        _keeperRegistry.addFunds(upkeepId, amount);
    }
}
```